# Pybluez2. Модуль bluetooth не импортируется

Tags: python-3.x, библиотеки, импорт, установка, bluetooth

После многократных неудачных попыток поставить **pybluez** на python3.11 (windows11, ×64bit), была совершена удачная попытка установить **pybluez2** (c помощью pip install pybluez). Установка прошла успешно, в терминале ошибок не возникло. Однако в программе import bluetooth подчёркивается как неизвестный модуль, будто и не устанавливалось ничего. Подскажите, с чем может быть связано, как исправить?

Может ли модуль bluetooth заменить socket? Например, есть ли аналог функции `discover_devices`?

Comment: Куда установили библиотеку? Какой интерпретатор в редакторе кода выбран? Какой редактор кода?

Comment: PyBluez2 установлен по следуещему пути: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages

Comment: Среда - visual studio code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас PyCharm:

> File -> Settings -> Project "название проекта(рабочей > директории") -> Python Interpreter ->  Кликаем на  "+" ->
> В поисковой строке находим "pybluez" -> Install packages